# watch for file changes on remote server

Tags: node.js, remote-server, file-watcher

I want to create a node.JS app to watch changes on a remote server, e.g. `//10.9.8.7/files_to_watch/*`.

All I need is watch if some new files/folders appear. I have found an npm package named `chokidar` and I managed to watch local files but I don't know how to watch remote disc (which is protected by password).

How should I do that? Should I first connect to that server (`ftp node package`) and then run watcher or what? And what is with optimization? What if there will be a lot of files and changes? Is it a good way I'm thinking?

Comment: Does this have to be done programmatically or can it be configured outside of the app?

Comment: programmatically

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev How would you do this if it can be configured outside of app?